# How to change a program's tray icon?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I have changed all my icons(manually) in the unity sidebar. I just want to change some of them in system tray( for example Deluge,vlc) without using icon themes.How to do it? Where are they located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually replace the icons by examining a `*.list` file, to find out where they are located. I don't know whether panel icons are set in `.desktop` files or not, however we could basically trick the program by saying "Yup, this custom image is totally the same file, saved under the same name, so go ahead and use that."

For instance, I have a `chinese-calendar` application installed. By examining the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/chinese-calendar.list`, I found there s `/usr/share/pixmaps/chinesecalendar-64.png` image, which is the tray icon used on the Unity panel. The next step is to save your desired icon under the same name as that file, e.g. `cp $HOME/my-custom-icon.png /usr/share/pixmaps/chinesecalendar-64.png`.

Keep in mind that the file is likely root owned, so you will need to use `sudo`, as well as back up that original icon just in case

Answer (score 0):

I needed this on Ubuntu 18.04, and set the icon in the dir `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/`.

Change it