# Change Tray Icons to monochrome theme

Tags: google-chrome, themes, icons

Trying to unify the visual look of my tray, and for the most part it's ok, but the Chrome icon is hideous and bright, when it should be muted and monochrome.  I searched around, and found a whole lot of nothing on the subject, aside from this: https://github.com/bil-elmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray and it is either broken or stopped being supported because the command to fetch the script is broken, so it won't install.  Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/703836/295286   Find the Chrome's `.list` file in  `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, it should give you a hint where icons located. Replace the icon with the one you want

Answer (score 0):

The script has been updated recently. It works pretty well right now; If you have any issue please report it, i would be more than happy to provide a fix as soon as possible.